# How to separate sessions for new browser instance of IE8 using servlet?

Tags: java, session, servlets

I am facing the problem of creating a new session and maintaining the previous one at the same time.

My code is in a Servlet. It works for all other browsers than IE and also for IE7 and lower versions, but not for IE8 and IE9. I knew very well that IE8 & IE9 uses the same session for every new request; but I want to create a new session for every new initial request for my Java EE application.
I wrote code for the creation of a new `HTTPSession` for the first time when a session is null and also added code for a new session.

What can I do to code changes for a new Session, without maintaining any hidden variable value on every page or sending a session ID through the URL? Is there any other way possible to separate two or more sessions?

My Servlet code snapshot is like the one below:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    process(request, response);
}

private void process (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String strErrorMsg = null;
    response.setContentType ( "text/html" );
    HttpSession session = null;
    Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();

    if (session == null) {
        ServletContext appContext = getServletContext();
        WebProcessContextBuilder builder =  WebProcessContextBuilder.getInstance();
        ProcessContext objContext = null;
        try {
            session = request.getSession(true);
            // Code for setting some initial session attributes and forwarding request 
            // to first window to display.
        }
    }

    if (session != null && session.isNew()) {
        // Code for new session to forward my request with saving session id 
        // as well as setting session attributes
    } else {
        // code for showing alert message like "Session active in another window or tab.";
    }
}
```

Using the above code, on the 2nd time when I tried the load the new application I'm always getting a error message. It's because I am getting a session that is not equal to null and `session.isNew` is always false in the case of IE8 & IE9. Elsewhere it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right:

```
HttpSession session = null;
Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();

if (session == null) {
```

How would session not be null here?

I think it should be:

```
// Try to get the session, but don't create one if there isn't one
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();

if (session == null) {
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for reply. U absolutely right in case of first time login only. But for accessing same url 2nd time, it copies same session. That is the main issue Im facing that how to sepearate them....

Comment: `session == null` will **always** be true at that point. You assign `null` to `session`, then don't change it before the comparison. So inside the `if` block you will create a new session if one didn't exist before - this isn't what you wanted.